# Why do we use ConformanceProfile in Hl7(Hapi)?

Tags: hl7, hapi

Why do we use the ConformanceProfile in Hl7 parsers?
As well as what is the difference between using,DefaultValidation and No Validation in HapiContext?
If i use, NoValidation and If my message has invalid tags it should parse  or fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand this way, I create a Healthcare PMS application and I want to generate ADT messages, But I cannot generate any arbirtary message without any defined structure or cardinality. Thats when I will create "Specification for my application" to specify What I can send from and recieve or accept in my application.

A conformance profile in hapi is like the application specs fed into the conformance tables (in .xml format), which  generates a message definition allowing you to specify maximum field lengths, required cardinalities.

If you are using Test Panel for HAPI you will understand that If you feed a message and use Validate:Default, then it perform a validation of the input message on a profile that HAPI has.

No Validation will not perform any validation against any profiles that exist. A simple example will outline it. There is a field called "Set ID" (`PV1.1` in below segment)

`PV1|1|O|NDE^^^^Ambulatory(s)^NMHOSP|R||||`

That field will always be numeric. If otherwise I specify no validation, then I can feed anything in the Set ID it can be an alphabet as well.

So this 
`PV1|1|O|NDE^^^^Ambulatory(s)^NMHOSP|R||||` will parse in Default or Using any other conformance profile

But this

`PV1|A|O|NDE^^^^Ambulatory(s)^NMHOSP|R||||` will only parse in No Validation and will fail in Default.